# Pointer to an object with explicit constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, explicit

I am trying to do something like this and I keep getting an error:

```
class A {
public:
    explicit A();
}

A * a = new A(); //results in:  undefined reference to A()
```

I also tried:

```
A * a = A(); //results in cannot convert A to A * in assignment
```

Is there a way to do this? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the problem is not related with the fact that the constructor is `explicit`, but with the fact that you have declared it and not defined it. What you are getting is an error from the *linker*, not from the compiler. Try this:

```
 class A {
 public:
     explicit A() { /* Or anything more meaningful than just doing nothing */ }
 };
```

In the second case, that won't work. First, because you're trying to initialize a pointer (i.e. a variable of type `A*`) from an object of type `A`. Second, because even if you did the slightly more meaningful:

```
A a = A();
```

That won't compile because `explicit` constructors are not considered for *copy-initialization* (the form of initialization that uses the `=` sign).

Comment: you're fast as all get out. I thought I had you on that one. LOL.

Comment: @TylerJandreau: lol, just a bunch of seconds, you'll win the next one ;)

Comment: I have access only to the header file, does this mean there is no implementation of it in the object file?

Comment: @user2487364: I guess so. Have you tried doing just `A a;`? It should give you the same linker error

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing the body of the constructor. Try:

```
class A {
public:
    explicit A() {}
}
```

The `explicit` keyword just means that it prevents type conversions, which is what the second error is saying.